# How to define SoftwareSerial pins on ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, softwareserial, arduino-yun, nodemcu

I'am new to arduino yun and ESP. In fact, i have an arduino yun which has a sim808 dfrobot shield on it which uploads GPS data online at a regular time interval.

I want to connect the dfrobot sim808 shield to esp so that the latter will send the data online thus making the system low cost by not using the arduino yun

```
#include  <DFRobot_sim808.h>
#include  <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include  <Console.h>

#define PIN_TX    10
#define PIN_RX    11
SoftwareSerial mySerial(PIN_TX, PIN_RX);
DFRobot_SIM808 sim808(&mySerial);//Connect RX,TX,PWR,
```

I want to know which pin on the sim808's TX and RX pin should be connected to the ESP8266 like define above, pin 0,1 are used by the yun for Wifi connectin so pin 10 and 11 are used. . By the way, I am currently using ESP8266 12E nodemcu. Please help me with that.